# More LinearLayout in a row inside a ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to put two LinearLayout in a ScrollView
The Project should be like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gsp5M.jpg)

And my Code is this

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.krusty.project">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="70dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:hint="Insert text"
        android:inputType="number"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
        android:text="-"
        android:onClick="decrement"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:text="text"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="+"
        android:onClick="increment"
        />
     </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I've tried with gravity and padding but when i add another linearlayout nothing is shown
I'll be very greatful if you find me a solution XD are two days that i'm on it but i can't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're so close!

A ScrollView can only contain one child, this child is usually a LinearLayout

Wrap the 2 LinearLayouts you want to use in another LinearLayout

```
 <ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

`ScrollView` should have only one direct child. I suggest you to use `RelativeLayout` as a direct child of the `ScrollView` and inside `RelativeLayout` you can do whatever you want to(except `ListView`). Also, if you want to achieve specific position you should learn the "`weight`" attribute of Layout.